# Change date format to number in R

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with data of over 20 years.

I want to derive from a R-format Date (%y%m%d) corresponding numbers between 1 and 366.
So that each Jan, 1st is "1", each Feb,29th is "60", each Dec, 31st is "366" and everything in between :)
For this step of my analysis, the year does not matter.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You wrote, "For this step of my analysis, the year does not matter.". Yes, it does. How else do you determine leap years and their extra day?

Comment: Take a look at `?strptime`

Comment: Of course, for leap years it does matter ;)  i wanted to make clear, that only need 1:366 as an output here and no further reference to a year.

Comment: @markus exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
date_char = "2021-02-05"
date = strptime(date_char, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
as.integer(strftime(date, format = "%j"))
```

Answer will be 36